# How long does crew change last?

Tags: flash-point

When I first read how the crew change works it appeared useless:

> Player may swap their existing Specialist card with and Specialist
>   card not currently in play. The player's Firefighter has the AP (less
>   the 2 AP required for a crew change) and special abilities of the
>   newly selected Specialist for the entire turn.

The last part that states "... for the entire turn" to me makes it sound like you switch back to your old role when your turn ends. If this is the case though, you never get a chance to do much of anything with the new role. This makes it sound like that actually is not the case and that you keep the new role for the remainder of the game. Can someone confirm that this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Crew Change lasts](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/895239/crew-change-only-for-1-turn) until you decide to change roles again. You don't automatically change back to your old role.  The "cost" is having to get back to the truck, finish the turn, and then spend the 2 AP to change.